# Issue in Passing Javascript variable to PHP file Through Ajax on Select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery calender which stores the date onselect and I want to send the selected date to php file to get results from database based on the selected date.. this is my code:-

```
enter code here<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Date:

`my scripr:-<script>`
var x='';
    $('#calendar').datepicker({

```
altField: '#datepicker_send',

    inline: true,

    firstDay: 1,

    showOtherMonths: true,

    altFormat: "dd/mm/yy",

    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",

    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],

     onSelect: function(dateText){
     $('#event-date').text(dateText)
      x=dateText;          
     // alert(x);
     $.ajax({ type: "GET", 
     url: 'check_events.php', 
     data: { y : x}, 
     //dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data)
     { alert(data); }   /// tried to get the value of date
          } );
    }
    });
</script>
```

Check_events.php:-

```
enter code here<?php mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("users") or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_REQUEST['y']))

{

$y = date_format($_REQUEST['y'],'YYYY-MM-DD');

echo $y;

exit; //trying to print the date

//$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($x);

$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date='$x'");

while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_check))

{

print_r($res);

}

}

?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET", 
 url: 'check_events.php', 
 data: { y : x}, 
 //dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data)
 { 
      alert(data); //Alert Data on success not result.
 }   
 });
```

Comment: changed the value.... but nothing is displaying on browser on execution of localhost/calender.php... can u help me out in finding the error?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the unnecessary `,` from here:

```
success: function(data),
```

So the new code should be:

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET", 
  url: 'check_events.php', 
  data: { y : x}, 
  //dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) { 
    alert(data); //Alert Data on success not result.
  }
});
```

Comment: removed , and changed result as data already ... same result nothing is displaying when executed on browser...

Comment: Use Mozilla Firefox's firebug. Try 'Console' tab there. Best of luck.